# Set type of accordion panel object in HTML dom element variable

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have a simple accordion defined like so

```html
<ngb-accordion>
  <ngb-panel #group>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
        <i [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-circle-down': group?.isOpen}">
```

Which works exactly as expected.  Now that I've upgraded to Angular 9 and added strict template checking, it fails on the `group?.isOpen` because it doesn't know what group's type is.  I can't figure out how to assign that `#group` properly.

For a nav, for example, I do `<nav #nav="ngbNav" ngbNav>` but I can't figure out the right name for a panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NgbPanel` [does not set](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.ts#L69) `exportAs` property, so this syntax will not work. As a workaround, I can only imaging redundant function in the component:

```js
panelTyped(panel): NgbPanel {
    return <NgbPanel>panel;
}
```

```html
<ngb-accordion>
  <ngb-panel #group>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
        <i [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-circle-down': panelTyped(group)?.isOpen}">
```